# mongo aggregate query not returning results

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have json like

```
{
 id:1,
 name: AAA,
 data:{}
 status: "Inactive"
 }
```

when I run the below aggregate query

```
db.database.aggregate({"$match": {"status" : "Inactive"}})
```

It doesn't work and 0 results are returned. I have to use the aggregate function and match to combine and run a bunch of queries.

Comment: The query looks fine.  Is `db.versionedCampaignDefinition` defined properly?  Does `db.versionedCampaignDefinition.aggregate({"$match": {})` return the entire collection?  It should.

Comment: db.database.aggregate({"$match": {"status" : "Inactive"}}) doesn't return anything.

Comment: `database` is the name of the collection?